# SCP permission denied

Tags: ubuntu, centos, ssh, scp, lxc

I have created two LXC containers on my host Ubuntu 16.0.4 one is Ubuntu and the other is Centos7 .I am trying to copy file from Centos7  using scp command to Ubuntu as root user it is asking for root password while I entered correct password it’s showing permission denied.May I know the possible reason why I am getting denied?[image]

Comment: Do you have SELinux running on the host?

Comment: Can root usually SSH to that host?

Comment: @Kusalananda  no I can’t it’s also same getting permission denied

Comment: @RamanSailopal  SElinux is disabled in Centos7

Comment: How are you running the containers? nspawn?

Comment: is root allowed in remote `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` (`PermitRootLogin Yes`) ?

Comment: @Archemar Thanks for your answer  it works

Comment: @RamanSailopal LXC

Answer (score 1):

By allowing the root in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` (PermitRootLogin  Yes), I was able to login.

according to `man sshd_config`

> ```
>  PermitRootLogin
>          Specifies whether root can log in using ssh(1).  The argument must be “yes”, “prohibit-password”, “without-password”, “forced-commands-only”,
>          or “no”.  The default is “prohibit-password”.
> ```

note that sshd must be restarted after a change in sshd_config.